# How to find duplicate values in a column in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I want to find duplicate from column ItemDescription and their ItemID Column from this data : [image: My Data]

Please advise me on how to do it.

Comment: What are you defining as a duplicate?

Comment: Also, there are various columns with `ID` in the name but none actually called just `ID` - which column do you want returned when looking for duplicates?

Comment: ItemDescription

Comment: Sorry for my bad, i already updated my question. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all duplicates, you can use this:

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemDescription
FROM tbimitems
WHERE ItemDescription IN (
    SELECT ItemDescription
    FROM tbimitems
    GROUP BY ItemDescription
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i will try it now, Hope it works.

Comment: Wow it's work, you're really helping. Thanks a lot master.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CTE:

```
With cte as
(
select row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID) as rk,ID from table
)
select ID from cte where rk>1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, although it's hard for me to understand your answer, but i really appreciate it.